# How to connect a sencha touch application with mysql database with a PHP backend?

Tags: php, mysql, json, sencha-touch

I know that this might have been answered some place else, but I'm still stuck and I've checked a lot of sources already. I already have my sencha list view, model, and store setup along with a mysql database with a PHP + json conversion. But it still won't display the result into my list view. My sencha app runs without errors at all. With a lot of research, I figured that I'm definitely doing something wrong defining the root property in my store class. The following is my PHP + json code with mysql queries to fetch data from the database:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("html_errors", true);

//checking connection and connecting to a database
require_once('connection/config.php');
//Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

//variables initialization
$out = "";
$action = "";
$data = "";

//check if read is set from the Teams class
if (isset($_REQUEST["action"])){
    $action = $_REQUEST["action"];
}
switch ($action) {
    case "read": $out = read_this();
    break;
}
echo utf8_encode($out);

//using function read_this() to retrieve teams from the tb_teams table then convert into json data
function read_this(){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT home_team_name FROM tb_teams")
    or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error());

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $i = 0;

    $eData = array("count" => $num, "fixtures" => array());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $eData["fixtures"][$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    return $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($eData) . ');';
}
?>
```

My model class:

```
    Ext.define('App.model.Team',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        config: {
            fields: [{name: 'home_team_name', type: 'string' }]
        },
    });
```

My store class:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Teams',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'App.model.Team',
        sorters: 'home_team_name',
        grouper: function(record) {
            return record.get('home_team_name')[0];
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'scripttag',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/backend/store.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'fixtures'
            },
            extraParams: {
                action: 'read'
            }   
        }   
    }
});
```

And my list view class:

```
Ext.define('App.view.TeamList',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'teamlist',

    config: {
            title: 'Teams',
            //loading data from Teams store into a List item and apply some properties
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: true,
            itemTpl: '{ home_team_name }',
            store: 'Teams',
    }
});
```

Please someone advise where exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. You are receiving the correct data? PHP sends the correct data in JSON format. Did you vaidate such a request? Does the store get filled? Can you post the data send from PHP without the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much observation, I found that the problem was actually at the PHP to json conversion (adapted from the sencha touch documentation) and how I handled the callback in the store class.

A working PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("html_errors", true);

//checking connection and connecting to a database
require_once('connection/config.php');
//Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

//variables initialization
$out = "";
$action = "";

//check if read is set from the Teams class
if (isset($_REQUEST["action"])){
    $action = $_REQUEST["action"];
}
switch ($action) {
    case "read": $out = read_this();
    break;
}
echo utf8_encode($out);

//using function read_this() to retrieve teams from the tb_teams table then convert into json data
function read_this(){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT home_team_name FROM tb_teams")
    or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error());

    $arr = array();

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    return $callback . '(' . json_encode($arr) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    return json_encode($arr);
}
}
?>
```

In the store class, I had to set autoLoad true, to enable autonomous reading of json data:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Teams',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'App.model.Team',
        sorters: 'home_team_name',
        grouper: function(record) {
            return record.get('home_team_name')[0];
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'scripttag',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/backend/store.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'fixtures'
            },
            extraParams: {
                action: 'read'
            }   
        }
        autoLoad true,   
    }
});
```

Thanks again for everyone who tried to help. I hope this saves other mates a great deal of time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment.

I think you should use `itemTpl: '{ name}'` inplace of `itemTpl: '{ home_team_name }'`. Because you declared `name` as a field in your model.

```
Ext.define('App.view.TeamList',{
      extend: 'Ext.List',
      xtype: 'teamlist',

      config: {
        title: 'Teams',
        //loading data from Teams store into a List item and apply some properties
        grouped: true,
        indexBar: true,
        itemTpl: '{ name}',
        store: 'Teams',
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback sagar. It doesn't matter how much reputation you have, what matters is you took some of your time to help out a mate. I tried your suggestion, but with no luck. Mainly because "name" is not actually a field, its a keyword used to declare a field. Thanks again for your thought.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are getting correct json form server; Sometimes adding height and width to list might help.

```
width: "95%",
height: "95%",
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I tried that, only reduced the width and height of the list view. Still nothing is showing up on the view and I don't see help coming from anyone really. The problem is there are some parts of the code that I'm not very familiar with such as the root property in the store class and its relationship with PHP or mysql.